# Implementation of breadth first search in PacMan

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I am currently working on a C++ project to make a PacMan clone. Basically I have done almost everything that the game does. But I have not yet figured out how to implement breadth first search in order for the ghosts to chase pacman. In the last few days, I have read a lot about BFS. I know what it is and what it does. I also know I have to use a queue for this purpose. But still, I am unable to actually implement this algorithm in my game. I have a 2d grid of 36*28 tiles. But I am really unsure about how to implement it in my xy-coordinate system, what to push to the queue and how to manipulate the neighbouring tiles. I'm stuck at this point. I'm not asking for actual code. I just need a clear and simple explanation about the actual implementation of BFS and which things to keep in mind while working on BFS in this 2d game grid.
Your explanation will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: "I am unable to actually implement this algorithm in my game." - It will be impossible to know what you're doing wrong without seeing what you've already *done*.  Frankly, given a grid, I'm not convinced a BFS is even *warranted*. A backtracking algorithm may be more worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do the BFS every time a ghost will do a move. What you could do is start a BFS from PacMan until he found all ghosts. Note that you don't actually need the complete route a ghost will take, you only need the next move. While doing the BFS you can store for each cell the distance from PacMan to that cell. When you BFS is done, all ghosts can look in their adjacent cells an pick the cell with the lowest number. Note that you should initialize all cells with a large number.

To do your BFS you can do some tricks, like mapping your (x, y) coordinate to one number. This number can be placed in your queue. Note you should check for wall before putting something in your queue. When you pull something out the queue run a for-loop of length 4 (the number of adjacent cells).

```
int dx[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
int dy[] = {1, 0, -1, 0};

void do_bfs() {
    std::queue<int> queue;
    // initialize grid
    // add starting position of pacman to queue

    while(!queue.empty()) {
        // remove and access first element
        cur_place = queue.front(); queue.pop(); 
        map_to_coordinate(cur_x, cur_y, cur_place);
        cur_distance = grid[cur_x][cur_y];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (cur_x + dx[i] >= 0 && /* more checks */) {
                queue.push_back(map_to_number(cur_x + dx[i], cur_y + dy[i]));
                grid[cur_x + dx[i]][cur_y + dy[i]] = cur_distance + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // now grid is filled, so now you should find out for each ghost how to move
}
```

As an exercise for the reader I tried to leave open as much while making my point.

Comment: Finally it works after some figuring out :) Your pseudo code and explanation certainly helped. Thank you.